# accelerated mobile pages in ASP.Net web forms possible?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I have a ASP.NET web forms application. I am trying to see whether it is possible to support AMP (accelerated mobile pages). Since the  tag is not allowed in AMP, I would assume it is impossible to support it. However, I can't seen to find a single article confirming this assumption.

Is it possible to generate AMP with ASP.Net web forms? If so, what is the approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application . It should bee helpful.

There is also amp-form which is used for this purpose. It can be checked at https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form .

Answer (score 1):

> I think you should have a look at
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application
>   . It should bee helpful.

This is't AMP, AMP (called Accelerated Mobile Page) is a spcial HTML syntax designed by Google. The Mobile Pages on ASP.NET are only optimized webforms 4 mobile devices.